# Executing two command at remote server and storing the output to local server using shell scripting

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I'm trying to clean up my shell script. I am trying to read the list of server for
a text file "serverlist" and shh each server to get the outcome of the command and store in to a file "result_segfault". I managed to do that however for each server i wanted to list the name of the server  and the output below:

Example :

```
-----------------
Servername
-----------------
Output of the command

----------------
Servername2
------------------
Output of the command
```

This is my code

```
#!/bin/bash


for HOSTNAME in $(cat serverlist);
do

SCRIPT="cat /var/log/messages | grep 'segfault at 0000000000000098'"

for HOSTNAME in ${HOSTNAME} ;
do
ssh ${HOSTNAME} "${SCRIPT}" >"result_segfault"

done;
done
```

I didn't know how to add the Server name and the separator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{
echo "----------------"
echo "$HOSTNAME"
echo "----------------"
ssh "$HOSTNAME" "${SCRIPT}"
} >>"result_segfault"
```

The braces `{...}` group statements together so that their stdout can be collected with a single redirect.  I used ">>" in place of ">" for the redirect because it appeared from your sample that you wanted to append together the results from each host rather than overwrite it each time a new host is queried.

Answer (score 0):

With various stylistic fixes;

```
#!/bin/bash

while read HOSTNAME
do
    ssh ${HOSTNAME} grep 'segfault at 0000000000000098' /var/log/messages
done <serverlist >result_segfault
```